# How to get sum of all Map values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have map where values are numbers. Is there any way to get the sum of all its values?

Example:

```
{"key1":6,"key2":5}
```

Thanks in advance

EDITED: Map example:

```
Map(2) {23 => 1, 24 => 3}
```

Comment: Have you tried loops? You can try `for...in` loop for start

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply loop over the Object and sum the values,

```js
const ob = {"key1":6,"key2":5}

let sum = 0;
for (let key in ob) {
  sum += ob[key];
}
console.log(sum);
```

A concise way could be:

```js
const ob = {"key1":6,"key2":5}

const sum = Object.values(ob).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

If you have a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), then you can loop over it and find the sum, maybe like shown below:

```js
const myMap = new Map([[23, 1], [24, 3]]);
let sum = 0;
myMap.forEach((v) => {
  sum += v;
});

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: sorry, I was mistaken with examle. now I attached real Map object that I have

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is an object, not a Map. To sum values, you can either use `for...in` or `Object.values().reduce`:

```js
const obj = {
  "key1": 6,
  "key2": 5
};

let sum = 0;

for (let prop in obj) {
  sum += obj[prop];
}

console.log(sum);
```

```js
const obj = {
  "key1": 6,
  "key2": 5
};

const sum = Object.values(obj).reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);

console.log(sum);
```